# Core Service logging

Tags: core-service

Does the Core Service create logs on the server where it is hosted? Looking at just the fault exception it's hard to determine the right issue.

For example, below a simple Copy method is giving null exception. `_Client` is being initialized properly.

```cs
RepositoryLocalObjectData objData= _Client.Copy(TCMUriOfPageToCopy, 
                                                LocationFolderToCopy, 
                                                true, 
                                                _ReadOption);
```

[image: As shown in image]

[image]

Comment: No callstack = no answer. Check all the parameters for null

Comment: Hi Andrey, I verified parameters are identifiable Object in CMS using core service. Added the stack trace snap.

Comment: Can you check if there's an error in Event viewer of CM server? BTW, it's better to insert text rather than screenshots.

Comment: I tried to copy the page manually in CMS and getting the same sort of error (80040356) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. <br/> I will try to copy some different page.

Comment: Do you have an event system?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your basic question, the logs are created where you want them to be created from the consumer application which is using the CoreService. You can create in log files on the servers where your consumer application is hosted using `log4net` or you can create `eventsource` and write it to any event log(Tridion or any other).

Also, if the code also invokes event system or any other Tridion module, then the respective logging will also be available via that system. 
Like, if you create a page using CoreService and if you have event system code on page creation, that module will get executed and you will see logs for the same as well (depends on where you are logging from the same) or if you publish a page via CoreService, you will see templating logs as well, just as an example. So, based on your use case, you will have to look for different avenues, but the primary source will be the consumer application as that is where you expect to catch exceptions (if any) or log appropriately to figure out success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

I fully expect there to be a possibility to enable some form of debug logging for the Core Service. I also fully expect this to be an internal use feature only (that is: internal to SDL R&D) as one would only ever need to debug the core service itself if the product was broken.

The fact that the NullPointerException happens on the side of the core service itself doesn't mean the core service is at fault; one of the parameters you passed contains invalid data (not a valid folder tcmuri, not a valid item tcmuri, invalid readoptions) or the core service client itself is no longer in a valid state (it may have been closed by another thread, server application got recycled, etc).

If you really are interested in logs generated by CoreService then there are two types of logging you can enable (they're not enabled by default):

**WCF tracing**
Uncomment the comment out nodes below `<system.diagnostics><sources>`; this will cause WCF to dump heaps of information about requests and responses.

The location of the logfile is configured in the `<sharedListeners>` node in the `initializeData` property of the child `<add>` node.

**Application logging**
Under `<loggingConfiguration><specialSources>` find the `<allEvents>` node. Set it's `switchValue` property to "All". Change the `<listener>` child node's `Name` property from "Tridion Event Log" to "Log File"

The default file location for the log file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log\TcmServiceHost.log"; you can change this in the `<loggingConfiguration><listeners><add name="Log File">` node by changing the `fileName` property.

Note that by default the application logs all informational and higher level messages to the event log.

Also note that if you connect to Core Service via HTTP/HTTPS instead of Net.TCP then the configuration file to modify is `webservices\web.config` as opposed to `bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config` as explained in the answer [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/accessing-configuration-from-events-system-when-triggered-via-the-core-service/1240#1240)

Comment: There's indeed core service logging and it's not internal. Feel free to turn it on in the app.config of you CoreService. It has commented out example, but be aware that it will affect performance a lot. In this case, message from CM event viewer should be enough to see the problem. I would be very surprised if core service would throw null ref, even with completely wrong parameters.

Comment: My point is: if you think the solution is to debug core service itself than you don't understand the problem well enough (or you should create a ticket for SDL support but that's an edge case).